# jsonschema2pojo make generated class implement Serializable interface

Tags: java, jsonschema2pojo

How can I force the jsonschema2pojo generated class to implement serializable interface?
I am parsing plain json and not JSON Schema so making the json contain "javaInterfaces" array is out of the question. Here is the working code:

```
    JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
    SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new GsonAnnotator(), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());
    mapper.generate(codeModel, className, packageName, jsonStr);
    return codeModel;
```

Comment: please mark an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
I could not find a way to implement Serializable but I can implement Parcelable which works for me.

```
GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
...
@Override
public boolean isParcelable() {
    return true;
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in [0.4.23](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/blob/873890e93c781d8ee428a765f1ced06c7db36d54/CHANGELOG.md#0423) (and later) of jsonschema2pojo. Just set the 'serializable' property to `true`:

```
GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
...
@Override
public boolean isSerializable() {
    return true;
}
...
}
```